# Elegant proof of the fact about a bounded set and a functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm looking for a proof of the following statement: if $X$ is a normed space and $Y\subset X$ is unbounded, then there exists a functional $f$ from the dual space $X^{'}$, so that $f(Y)$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$.
I can prove it this way: I find a sequence $y_n$ from $Y$, such that all finite subsequences of it are linearly independent and that $\|y_n\|\to \infty$. Then I define $f(y_n)=\|y_n\|$. Then I use Hahn-Banach to conclude, that $f$ can be extended to the bounded functional on the whole $X$.
But I don't like this proof, it's too technical. Do somebody know a more elegant one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didnt call the Hahn Banach theorem too technical. I meant my argumentation with subsequences too technical. Because actually i have to distinguish between the case when $Y$ is finite-dimensional subspace and the case when $Y$ is infinite-dimensional. Its clear, that we have to use Hahn-Banach there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not valid. If $Y=\{x,2x,3x,..\}$ where $x$ is a non-zero vector, then $Y$ is unbounded but you cannot find sequence $(y_n)$ in it such that any finite number of terms of the sequence is linearly independent. Linear independence cannot be used in the argument.

This result is actually an exercise on Uniform Boundeness Principle. Let us assume that $f(Y)$ is bounded for each $f\in X$ and show that $Y$ must be bounded in this case. For each $y \in Y$ define $F_y$ on $X'$ by $F_y(f)=f(y)$. It is given that this collection of continuous linear functionals is bounded at each point $f$. By Uniform Boundeness Principle we conclude that $\|F_y\|$ is bounded which means that $Y$ is bounded. [Because $\|F_y\|=\|y\|$].

Comment: That's why i wrote in the comment above that i have to  distinguish between the case when Y is finite-dimensional subspace and the case when Y is infinite-dimensional. For the finite-dimensional $Y$ I need the separate proof, but it's not difficult. Thank You though for Your proof, its nicer.